# Google Cloud Storage : Can we Get file or Search file based on meta data?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

While Uploading Object , I have assigned metadata using `x-goog-meta-<keyname>`.

Currently to get file , we have to use Get Object using Key/Filename.
I want know is it possible like Get Object using META-DATA ?

Is there any way we can directly get/search file by passing metadata ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot.

You can retrieve the metadata via the object name, but you cannot retrieve the object name via the metadata.

If you really needed to, you could create a second bucket that contained objects with the metadata names with data or metadata that referred to the original object name in the first bucket.